# Problema con Bootstrap y Wordpress

Tags: php, bootstrap, wordpress, wordpress-plugin, plugin

resulta que estoy haciendo un pequeño plugin para Wordpress. La idea es que en la página que el usuario quiera se genere un par de containers con unos formularios.

Esto lo tengo hecho con un Shortcode que devuelve todo lo necesario para montarlo. Hasta aquí no hay problema, funciona todo perfecto. **El problema** viene cuando necesito que Bootstrap abra un modal. Parece que no está cogiendo la parte de JS de Bootstrap.

A parte de esta librería tengo JQuery, la parte de CSS de Bootstrap... etc. Y todas funcionan perfectamente.

La librería la estoy metiendo desde la página de configuración del plugin:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ws_header_scripts', 10);
function ws_header_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '5.1.3', true);
}
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Es dificil ayudar cuando no se pone todo el código.  Necesitariamos ver el HTML del modal, por si acaso alli vemos algo raro.  Sino entramos en el mundo de la adivinación absoluta. Voy a intentarlo, venga... deduciendo que estás usando bootstrap 5 por lo que has pegado en la pregunta, se me ocurre que podria ser el ya típico problema de mezclar atributos `data-` de bootstrap 4 o inferiores dentro de bootstrap 5, que **ya no usa ese atributo**, sino que en la versión 5 debes cambiar todos los atributos **data-** de tu HTML por **data-bs-**.  Ya me dirás si he acertado. Saludos!

Comment: Efectivamente, es el atributo data-bs. No había puesto fragmento de código porque es una cosa que utilizo mucho y nunca me había dado problemas, pero es cierto que estaba utilizando versiones anteriores.
Muchísimas gracias!